# Bug in TFS MultiInference rpc method (undefined behavior)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to use MultiInference method to check two different versions of some model in one request (A/B test). However in some case I've got an error `Duplicate evaluation of signature: classification`, and in another case I've got really strange results.

Examples:

1. This is the case, when I as for model "stpeter" in versions 7 & 8, and signature_name = "classification" (both tasks).

```
Input request:
tasks {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 7
    }
    signature_name: "classification"
  }
  method_name: "tensorflow/serving/classify"
}
tasks {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 8
    }
    signature_name: "classification"
  }
  method_name: "tensorflow/serving/classify"
}
input {
  example_list {
    examples {
      features {
        feature {
          key: "inputs"
          value {
            bytes_list {
              value: "ala.kowalska"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ab_test.py", line 146, in <module>
    do_inference(args)
  File "ab_test.py", line 123, in do_inference
    results = stub.MultiInference(request, 10)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/ents/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 533, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/ents/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Duplicate evaluation of signature: classification"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1549359403.703597000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Duplicate evaluation of signature: classification","grpc_status":3}"
>
```

2. So, change one of `signature_name`.

```
Input request:
tasks {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 7
    }
    signature_name: "classification"
  }
  method_name: "tensorflow/serving/classify"
}
tasks {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 8
    }
  }
  method_name: "tensorflow/serving/classify"
}
input {
  example_list {
    examples {
      features {
        feature {
          key: "inputs"
          value {
            bytes_list {
              value: "ala.kowalska"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Results:
results {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 7
    }
    signature_name: "classification"
  }
  classification_result {
    classifications {
      classes {
        label: "BOT"
        score: 0.010155047290027142
      }
      classes {
        label: "HUMAN"
        score: 0.9898449182510376
      }
    }
  }
}
results {
  model_spec {
    name: "stpeter"
    version {
      value: 7
    }
    signature_name: "serving_default"
  }
  classification_result {
    classifications {
      classes {
        label: "BOT"
        score: 0.010155047290027142
      }
      classes {
        label: "HUMAN"
        score: 0.9898449182510376
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to work well (there is not error). But let's look closer for results. We can see answer from stpeter in version 7 for both tasks (signature_name="classification" and signature_name="serving_default"), despite task #2 has defined: `version {value: 8}`.

Served model was created using Tensorflow estimators and saved using `export_savedmodel`. Sice we have available signatures:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Classify: ['serving_default', 'classification']
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Regress: ['regression']
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Predict: ['predict']
```

There is not limitations for model version in [inference.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/aa35cfdb24016f6d88f82c53d45c8ce9fa550499/tensorflow_serving/apis/inference.proto).

I also checked [TFS test cases](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/64f50602342e3a998f87b5340ed40082ab650fcb/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server_test.py#L405), but it seems like my case wasn't checked.

I will be very grateful if only for a small tip that will help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that a MultiInference request is designed to be applied to a single saved model, on a model version granularity level. In fact, the model version specified by the first model spec in the request is the only one that matters (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/multi_inference_helper.cc#L30)).
It would probably be cleaner to enforce the same model version, just like the same model name is already enforced [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/inference.proto#L26).
Then the above comment would be updated with something like:
"All ModelSpecs in a MultiInferenceRequest must access the same model name and version."

Happy to help with any additional concerns.